# Variable 'loginusername' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I'm getting an error that saying string does not have an value. but i have assigned a value but somehow there is an error that i cant see. please help.

> Variable 'loginusername' is used before it has been assigned a value.
> A null reference exception could result at runtime.
>
> Variable 'loginpword' is used before it has been assigned a value. A
> null reference exception could result at runtime.

when i changed the data type of loginusername & loginpword the error goes away but i need this to be string data types.

```
        Dim strFile As String = "D:\DBSystem\Connection\connconfig.dbs"
        Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(strFile)
        Dim ip As String
        Dim port As String
        Dim userid As String
        Dim password As String
        Dim database As String

        'reading
        ip = sr.ReadLine()
        port = sr.ReadLine()
        userid = sr.ReadLine()
        password = sr.ReadLine()
        database = sr.ReadLine()
        sr.Close()


        'default connection code
        Dim serverstring As String = "server=" & ip & ";port=" & port & ";database=" & database & ";user ID=" & userid & ";password=" & password & ";OldGuids=true"
        Dim sqlconnection As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection
        sqlconnection.ConnectionString = serverstring
        Dim Reader As MySqlDataReader
        Dim loginpword As String
        Dim loginusername As String

        Try
            If sqlconnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                sqlconnection.Open()
                Dim sqlstatement As String = "SELECT Username,Password FROM SDS_Users WHERE `Username` =' " & Login_tb_username.Text & "'"
                Dim Command = New MySqlCommand(sqlstatement, sqlconnection)
                Reader = Command.ExecuteReader

                While Reader.Read
                    loginpword = Reader.GetString("Password")
                    loginusername = Reader.GetString("Username")

                End While

                Reader.Close()

                If Login_tb_username.Text = loginusername And Login_tb_password.Text = loginpword Then
                    Me.Visible = False
                    Main_window.Visible = True
                    sqlconnection.Close()
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Username & Password doesn't match any account!", "Error",
                   MessageBoxButtons.OK)
                End If
            Else
                sqlconnection.Close()
                MsgBox("Connection Error!", "Error")

            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are assigning values to your variables in the following code block:

```
While Reader.Read
    loginpword = Reader.GetString("Password")
    loginusername = Reader.GetString("Username")
End While
```

As the `Reader` is the result of a database query, it is not guaranteed to contain values. The content of the `While` block is may not be executed, hence the error you are getting.

To work around this error, simply initialise the variables with a default/initial value, such as:

```
Dim loginpword As String = ""
Dim loginusername As String = ""
```

Comment: IMHO, the best way to create string is Dim loginPword = "", since it is harder to forget to assign a value, and avoids the null exception and redundancy.

Comment: @CarlosTadeu `Dim loginPword = ""` requires `Option Infer On` which some people prefer not to use.